# Python & win32security - Appcrash on setting permissions

Tags: python, winapi, file-permissions, pywin32

i've created a python-tool to set permissions on our file-server.
it's working - but not stable.
there are the funktions "set_permission" and "delete_permission" as you see below.
The "path_and_rights"-parameter is a tuple containing path as str, permissions as int and inheritance as int. This functions are called many times in a series.

Randomly, CPU and RAM of the Python-Process run high, until os (Win Server 2012R2) kills the process.
The critical place ist dacl.SetEntriesInAcl([newacl,]) - i added a "time.sleep(5)" around, that helped a bit, so i think there ist something non-blocking in the background and the next access runs into trouble (?)
After restart, the problematical path is processed without trouble, and the crash occurs on one of the next calls of the function. (1 to 10).

additional info:
Code runs fine under Win10 - maybe a bug under Win Server 2012?

Some ideas on solving that?
Thanks a lot!

```
import win32security
import time

def set_permission(path_and_rights,principal):
    usr=win32security.LookupAccountName(None,principal)[0]
    sd = win32security.GetNamedSecurityInfo(path_and_rights[0], win32security.SE_FILE_OBJECT,  win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
    dacl=sd.GetSecurityDescriptorDacl()
    newacl={
        'AccessMode': win32security.GRANT_ACCESS,
        'AccessPermissions': path_and_rights[1],
        'Inheritance': path_and_rights[2],
        'Trustee':{
            'TrusteeType': win32security.TRUSTEE_IS_GROUP,
            'TrusteeForm': win32security.TRUSTEE_IS_SID,
            'Identifier': usr}}
    time.sleep(5)
    dacl.SetEntriesInAcl([newacl,])
    time.sleep(5)
    win32security.SetNamedSecurityInfo(path_and_rights[0], win32security.SE_FILE_OBJECT,
        win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION |
        win32security.UNPROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
        None, None, dacl, None)

def delete_permission(path_and_rights,principal):
    usr=win32security.LookupAccountName(None,principal)[0]
    sd = win32security.GetNamedSecurityInfo(path_and_rights[0], win32security.SE_FILE_OBJECT, win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
    dacl=sd.GetSecurityDescriptorDacl()
    for aclnum in range(dacl.GetAceCount()):
        aacl=dacl.GetAce(aclnum)
        if aacl[2] == usr and aacl[1] == path_and_rights[1] and aacl[0][1] == path_and_rights[2]:
            dacl.DeleteAce(aclnum)
            win32security.SetNamedSecurityInfo(path_and_rights[0], win32security.SE_FILE_OBJECT,
            win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION |
            win32security.UNPROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
            None, None, dacl, None)
            return
```

this is the message on APPCRASH:

```
Problemsignatur:
  Problemereignisname:  APPCRASH
  Anwendungsname:   python.exe
  Anwendungsversion:    3.8.6150.1013
  Anwendungszeitstempel:    5f6b7010
  Fehlermodulname:  StackHash_6776
  Fehlermodulversion:   6.3.9600.19994
  Fehlermodulzeitstempel:   60653cd2
  Ausnahmecode: c0000374
  Ausnahmeoffset:   PCH_63_FROM_ntdll+0x0000000000090B9A
  Betriebsystemversion: 6.3.9600.2.0.0.400.8
```

Edit:
i tested on another machine - same os, same python-version (3.8.6):
running perfectly.

So now i have to find out what else could be the reason?
Any suggestions on how to debug?

Comment: This seems to be a problem with Windows Server: Database maintenance utility corrupts a Windows group name that includes non-ASCII characters, which causes `SetEntriesInAcl` errors.

Comment: couldn't find non-ASCII characters in any acl (existing + new).
That wouldn't also explain why it works fine on other servers.
I expect any other programm running on this server now as souce of trouble.
Now i added 40s of waiting between every step - no more Errors...

Answer (score 2):

i altered my code completely, now working with 'pythonnet' without any trouble.
Thanks for reading & help!

(Maybe someone knows a solution with the win32-libary, feel free to post it here)

````
import clr
import System

from System.IO import Directory
from System.Security.AccessControl import (
    AccessControlType,
    FileSystemAccessRule,
    FileSystemRights,
    PropagationFlags,
)

def set_permission(path_and_rights,principal):
    accessControl = Directory.GetAccessControl(path_and_rights[0])
    accessRule = FileSystemAccessRule(principal,
                                      path_and_rights[1],
                                      path_and_rights[2],
                                      getattr(PropagationFlags, "None"),
                                      AccessControlType.Allow,
                                      )
    accessControl.AddAccessRule(accessRule)
    Directory.SetAccessControl(path_and_rights[0], accessControl)

def delete_permission(path_and_rights,principal):
    accessControl = Directory.GetAccessControl(path_and_rights[0])
    accessRule = FileSystemAccessRule(principal,
                                      path_and_rights[1],
                                      path_and_rights[2],
                                      getattr(PropagationFlags, "None"),
                                      AccessControlType.Allow,
                                      )
    accessControl.RemoveAccessRuleAll(accessRule)
    Directory.SetAccessControl(path_and_rights[0], accessControl)```
````